# Pushing data from a classic ASP site to SharePoint

Tags: javascript, web-services, asp.net

We have a publicly facing classic ASP site and I need to capture some data from that site and push it to SharePoint and vice versa.

There are a few options as far as I know;

1. Writing a custom web service and consume it in Javascript/jQuery in the ASP application.
2. Using REST interface  in Javascript/jQuery.

What would you guys suggest to sort this problem? What are the difficulties using SharePoint apis in a "non-.Net" language? Or do you think that would be easier to write the form capture pages in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling the SharePoint web services (REST or otherwise) then it'd be no different to calling any other web service. They are just web services like any other.

If you're comfortable with calling web services in Javascript I'd just go with that, it'll be the least intrusive (as far as development goes).

Answer (score 1):

For ASP Classic integrations with SharePoint, you should be able to use the approach described on the following blog: http://blog.bendsoft.com/2012/09/introduction-to-com-in-camelot-net-connector-2/.